# file locked on upload SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a user on a site and whenever he uploads a file (online or sync), the status is always locked.
This only happens with this 1 user and on this site.

I've tried removing him from the site and re-adding him, but I can't find what is going on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a modern or classic SharePoint Online site?  Is check-in / check-out required for this library?  Is it a classic publishing site?

Comment: It's a modern site, and no check-in/check-out is not a requirement.
In the library settings I have set the setting Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited? to No.
Thanks mate

Comment: What is "lock"? Is there any error message on the UI? A simple screenshot may be more helpful. In addition, what are the permissions of this user? You can also test whether the same problem occurs in other libraries.

Comment: Not locked, but checked out

Answer (score 0):

I got this the other day from a user on a classic site.  Wait 12 hours and the lock will be released.  This is not configurable.  This has to do with something in the background that is not admin configurable- it’s in the M365 black hole category.